# How to get data from json in a mysql query correctly?

Tags: mysql, json

I'm trying to pull data from json and insert it into a table. New rows appear in the table by number as in json, but all fields have an empty value, NULL. Please help me figure it out.

```
[{"name":"ivan","city":"london","kurs":"1"},{"name":"lena","city":"tokio","kurs":"5"},{"name":"misha","city":"kazan","kurs":"3"}]

SET @json = CONVERT(LOAD_FILE('/var/lib/mysql-files/myfile.json') using utf8mb4);
REPLACE INTO test (name, city, kurs)
SELECT   
  JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.name') as name,
  JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.city') as city,
  JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.kurs') as kurs
FROM JSON_TABLE(@json,'$[*]' COLUMNS (data JSON PATH '$')) jsontable
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this, (and change `VARCAR(20)` to the appropriate definition):

```
set @json = '[{"name":"ivan","city":"london","kurs":"1"},{"name":"lena","city":"tokio","kurs":"5"},{"name":"misha","city":"kazan","kurs":"3"}]';

select * from json_table(@json,'$[*]' columns(name varchar(20) path '$.name',
                                              city varchar(20) path '$.city',
                                              kurs varchar(20) path '$.kurs')) as jsontable;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=403930af8ea05f5b553763e61a5faec9)

output:

| name | city | kurs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ivan | london | 1 |
| lena | tokio | 5 |
| misha | kazan | 3 |