# How to write JSON to Mysql?

Tags: mysql

sorry for my bad english.
I am inserting a json into mysql like this:

```
set @json = '[{"name":"ivan","city":"london","kurs":"1", },{"name":"lena","city":"tokio","kurs":"5"},{"name":"misha","city":"kazan","kurs":"3"}]';
select * from json_table(@json,'$[*]' columns(name varchar(20) path '$.name',
                                              city varchar(20) path '$.city',
                                              kurs varchar(20) path '$.kurs')) as jsontable;
```

But now there is a task to insert an unknown number of additional properties:

```
set @json = '[{"name":"ivan","city":"london","kurs":"1","options": [{
        "ao_id": 90630,
        "name": "Высота предмета",
        "value": "3.7 см"
    }, {
        "ao_id": 90673,
        "name": "Ширина предмета",
        "value": "4 см"
    }, {
        "ao_id": 90745,
        "name": "Ширина упаковки",
        "value": "4 см"
    }]},{"name":"lena","city":"tokio","kurs":"5", "options": [{
        "ao_id": 90630,
        "name": "Высота предмета",
        "value": "9.7 см"
    }]},{"name":"misha","city":"kazan","kurs":"3", "options": [{
        "ao_id": 90999,
        "name": "Высота",
        "value": "5.7 см"
    }]}]';
```

How can I best do this so that I can access the table in the future (search, index, output)?

Comment: How are you _inserting a json into mysql_ using a SELECT? I am afraid you may need to explain a little more clearly. Maybe use a translator, write in your languageand then translate to english and post that

Comment: @RiggsFolly, https://dbfiddle.uk/18wXe-X_   Oh yeah. I didn't write everything. I do REPLACE INTO I do following this example. Here is my question earlier. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71901852/how-to-get-data-from-json-in-a-mysql-query-correctly

Comment: _How can I best do this so that I can access the table in the future (search, index, output)?_ Dont store it as JSON in the database. Use the relational database as intended, then Search/Index and Output will be quite simple